# Windows what is NetCrawl service?

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, services, system-preferences

In my services in Windows I have NetCrawl I read that it is some sort of ad managing software that is absolutely not needed and even better disabled. Is it so? Can I just disable it everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

NetCrawl adware is installed on your computer, it will display underlined words that will show pop up advertisements and other unwanted ads in your browsers

- Search for ADWcleaner.exe only from Bleepingcomputers.com
- Run app > [Scan] then wait 20 sec or so then check each result folder below for results > if not sure> just [Clean] > [enter]> to reboot when prompted

Run this program after you install any new program when in doubt. it is a reliable adware removal tool.

- Be more wise in future when adding programs with unknown adware.
- Get Winpatrol (free) to alert you when startup apps or - services etc change on your system.
- another useful tool for startup alerts is Mike L's STARTUPMONITOR.EXE , no longer updated but still useful and very low overhead.